# How to adjust the verticle distance between two lines of text in a div without using position?

Tags: html, css, height, whitespace, distance

I have two lines of text that compose a title and date section for small little blog I'm making. I want to adjust the vertical distance between the two so that the second line of text is almost directly underneath the first. As it stands right now, there is a giant gap between the two. What is the standard fix for this? I have tried adjusting the position variable in the past, but it always makes the resizing of my website wonky. I would prefer not to mess with this. Thanks!

```css
.StoriesTitle {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 23%;
  height: 10px;
}

.chinese {
  font-family: "Yu Gothic";
  font-weight: normal;
}

.StoriesDate {
  padding-bottom: 10pt;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 1pt;
}
```

```html
<section class="stories">
  <div class="StoriesTitle">
    <h2>Title Length</h2>
    <div class="StoriesDate">
      <h3>2018<span class="chinese">年</span>09<span class="chinese">月</span> 28<span class="chinese">日</span</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the margin from `h2` and `h3` tags and add `height: auto` to your StoriesTitle class.

```css
h2, h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.stories {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.StoriesTitle {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 23%;
  height: auto;
}

.chinese {
  font-family: "Yu Gothic";
  font-weight: normal;
}

.StoriesDate {
  padding-bottom: 10pt;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 1pt;
}
```

```html
<section class="stories">
  <div class="StoriesTitle">
    <h2>Title Length</h2>
    <div class="StoriesDate">
      <h3>2018<span class="chinese">年</span>09<span class="chinese">月</span> 28<span class="chinese">日</span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.StoriesTitle h2 { 
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.StoriesDate h3 { 
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the margin of your h2 and h3 elements

```css
.StoriesTitle {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 23%;
  height: 10px;
}

.chinese {
  font-family: "Yu Gothic";
  font-weight: normal;
}

.StoriesDate {
  padding-bottom: 10pt;
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin-left: 1pt;
}

.StoriesTitle > h2, .StoriesDate > h3 {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="stories">
  <div class="StoriesTitle">
    <h2>Title Length</h2>
    <div class="StoriesDate">
      <h3>
        2018<span class="chinese">年</span>09<span class="chinese">月</span> 28<span class="chinese">日</span>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```